# Getting javax.naming.CommunicationException: Connection reset and AD "event ID 1216" while trying to perform LDAP search using JNDI and GSSAPI

Tags: active-directory, ldap, java, kerberos, gssapi

I am trying to analyze the reason for exceptions/ failures during the Ldap search. I am performing operations using JNDI on Active directory domain controller.

**Here is the background for the things that I am trying to do:**

1. Using SASL (`Kerberos authentication`) using JAAS (`KRB5LoginModule`) to generate a `LoginContext`.
2. Once the login is successful, `LoginContext` instance has the authenticated subject which has the kerberos ticket (`TGT`) populated in its `PrivateCredentials`
3. After that, I generate the LdapContext using GSSAPI using the above authenticated `Subject`.
4. Once the `LdapContext` is generated, I use it to perform JNDI operations **(mostly search using paging)**

---

5. Till now everything is fine and LdapContext is generated correctly
6. Some details of the Active Directory Domain Controller settings:
7. The lifetime of the TGT is set to be `1 hour`
8. The lifetime of the **service ticket**(`TGS`) is set to be 10 minutes (required due to some constraints, but this is how it is)

---

**Now the Scenario:**

- Using the the `LdapContext` created above, it starts querying the domain controller using the `pagingcontrol` and things work smooth for certain amount of time or certain amount of searches (lets say this so that I don't want you all to misguide that this might actually involve time, just consider this occurs after (approx.) regular intervals -  those intervals could be time or searches
- When it goes to get the next page after a certain interval, the search fails with :

  ```
     Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Connection reset
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.getSearchReply(LdapCtx.java:1920) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:130) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:217) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:189) ~[?:1.8.0_73]

        ... 10 more

     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.SaslInputStream.readFully(SaslInputStream.java:166) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.SaslInputStream.fill(SaslInputStream.java:123) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.SaslInputStream.read(SaslInputStream.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:860) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
  ```

At the same time, I see following event logs on Active Directory domain controller: EventId: **2889**

```
 Log Name:      Directory Service
 Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService
 Event ID:      2889
 Task Category: LDAP Interface
 Level:         Information
 Keywords:      Classic
 User:          ANONYMOUS LOGON
 Computer:      myad01.example.lab
 Description:The following client performed a SASL (Negotiate/Kerberos/NTLM/Digest) LDAP bind without
 requesting signing (integrity verification), or performed a simple bind over a clear text (non-
 SSL/TLS-encrypted) LDAP connection. 

 Client IP address: X.X.X.X:56260 
 Identity the client attempted to authenticate as:EXAMPLE\Administrator 
 Binding Type:0
```

I also see a log with EventID: 1216. The details are as follows:

```
 Log Name:      Directory Service
 Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService
 Event ID:      1216
 Task Category: LDAP Interface
 Level:         Warning
 Keywords:      Classic
 User:          N/A
 Computer:      myad01.example.lab
 Description:Internal event: An LDAP client connection was closed because of an error. 

 Client IP:X.X.X.X:56244 

 Additional Data 
 Error value: 1236 The network connection was aborted by the local system. 
 Internal ID: c060420
```

---

My understanding: Whenever (after some interval) it goes to get the next page the `ldap connection` is invalidated by the server ( as suggested by the event id **`1216`**) due to which I am getting the `CommunicationException` . My question is Why am I getting this after certain interval and not immediately? **Is it because the validity of the kerberos and service tickets is over?**
If this is the case, then how should I design to overcome my paging issues? Because, after getting communication exception, if I create a new LdapContext and set the paging control I get following exception as expected:

```
  javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 12 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B0B, comment: Error processing control, data 0, v3839 ]
     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
     at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
```

It is really important for me to have both the support - SASL(kerberos) for authentication and GSSAPI for LdapContext creation. Also, Paging is important as the data is huge and we can't have any restrictions on ticket validity as I can't control the cutomers' environments!

Please provide me with pointers on how to debug this issue further and suggest a proper way or a workaround (sorry for this, but need it anyway) to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My observations might help someone to analyze their issue. First of all `Event ID:1216` is generated on the Active Directory when the client (as in my question, I have mentioned JNDI, in this case the client is nothing but the LdapContext/DirContext) closes its underlying `Socket`.[Have a look at this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/event-id-1216-directory-services-event-log).

`LdapContext` is nothing but a connection, formed using certain connection settings, between a client(for ex: JNDI) and the LDAP server(for ex: Active Directory Directory services). When there is a connection between any two entities on network, it is usually backed by the formation of Client side socket and a server side socket. In case of LdapContext as well, LdapContext has an underlying socket.

While using `GSSAPI` for getting the instance of LdapContext, the underlying socket comes with a timeout equal to the [validity the service ticket lifetime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/maximum-lifetime-for-service-ticket) setting present on the AD DS. Once the validity/ timeout of the underlying socket ends, the socket gets closed. If, the `LdapContext` then tries to query AD DS then the above mentioned `Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Connection reset` exception occurs and communication fails.

As, the lifetime/ validity settings for TGT and TGS are on AD DS, there is no way to by pass them using GSSAPI. If incase there is a requirement such that it is required to use the `LdapContext` for more time, then the only way out is to increase the validity of the respective tickets.